# Way to make a Local dns server to Resolve .local domains

Tags: dns

So Im in the process of cleaning up my network and What I would like to do is setup a local DNS server to have my media server be Media.Local, file server be files.local, etc. While still being able to resolve normal TLDs

How would I go about this?

Comment: That's pretty vague... What operating systems, network size, current server(s), etc are you using? Could simple netbios resolution work?